# How to count csv files with specific naming structure in s3 bucket using boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I have files with many different names in a s3 bucket.

I want to count how many csv's with the word 'member' are in my bucket?

However the member files have an UUID attached them like so:

```
member_asldf2323209.csv
```

I have tried this so far:

```
import boto3

# create the s3 resource
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# get the file object
obj = s3.Object('bucket_name', 'key')

# read the file contents in memory
file_contents = obj.get()["Body"].read()

# print the occurrences of the new line character to get the number of lines
print file_contents.count('\n')
```

this only gets me one 'member' file with no UUID attached.

Comment: Are you wanting to count the number of _objects_ with the word `member` in the filename (Key), or are you wanting to look _inside_ the object for the word `member`? Why is your code counting the number of lines in the object? And where are you getting the values for `s3.Object('bucket_name', 'key')`? The code is only accessing a single object, is this intentional?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein very new to AWS so pardon the code, experimenting here. I am wanting to count the number of objects with the word member in the filename. thats it. I want to use that measure for logic operations in my lambda functions. To add I really just want to do a string match like so `member_` on each of the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to count the number of objects that contain a particular word in the Key, you could use something like:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2')

listing = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')

members = [object['Key'] for object in listing['Contents'] if 'member' in object['Key']]
print (members)
print (len(members))
```